# Timezone of Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase-analytics

I noticed that Firebase Analytics builds its daily reports based on irrelevant timezone (UTC+3 in my case)

How can I change time zone Firebase Analytics is building its reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See their [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7663853?hl=en), it is present

[image]

1. Open your Firebase project.
2. Click Dashboard, then click  (Settings).
3. Under Data Sharing, select the different ways in which you want to share your Analytics data.
4. Under Reporting, select the time zone and currency you want to use for your reports.

Answer (score 4):

**As of 2021 May >Go to Project Settings >Integrations >Google Analytics :-**

[image]

Comment: this is setting for google analytics not for firebase report

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers provided worked for me. **As of Nov, 2021**, this is how you can change the reporting time zone:

1- In Firebase, go to **Dashboard** page then click on **View more in Google Analytics** found top right.
[Show the location of the above options on Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDUyD.png)

2- On Google Analytics page the previous button took you to, go to **Admin** settings, then select **Property Settings**.
[Show the location of the above options on Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JMpd.png)

3- You can then change the **Reporting time zone** under **Property details**
[Show the Reporting time zone option on Property Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmlgX.png)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed update regarding the shifting sands of Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

Analytics settings moved again. New icon is in top right and you'll find the time settings there again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Analytics uses the timezone associated with the developer who created the Firebase Project.

To change the timezone you need to go in Project Settings, and change the time zone for each app.

See screenshots below.
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you guide where I can do that? On Project settings I can only change project name. Maybe there are some other place?

Comment: I've added some screenshots in my answer.

Comment: you wont believe but I have no Time zone input: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3m4o56yyy0znff/firebase-settings.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you the owner of the firebase project? Are you sure you have full access?

Comment: Do not see this option in an Account for which I am owner. Is this still available ?

Comment: Found it ! It is inside the Analytics Settings now.